# Finding an intersection between something and a line

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a set of points which are interpolated with an unknown method, or to be more precise, the method is known but it can be one of the several - it can be polynomial interpolation, spline, simple linear ... - and a line, which, let's for now imagine it is given in the simple form of *y = ax + b*.

For interpolation, I don't know what method is used (i.e. the function is *hidden*), so I can only determine y for some x, and equally, x for a given y value.

What is the usual way to go about finding an intersection between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Say your unknown function is `y = f(x)` and the line is `y = g(x) = ax + b`. The intersection of these curves will be the zeroes of `Δy = f(x) - g(x)`. Just use any [iterative method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) to find the roots of `Δy` - the simplest would be to use the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

Answer (score 1):

You have (an interpolation polynomial) f1(x) and (a line) f2(x) and you want to solve f(x) = f1(x)-f2(x) = 0. Use [any method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aRoot-finding_algorithms) for solving this equation, e.g. [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or even [bisection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). This may not be the most optimal for your case. Pay attention to convergence guarantees and possible multiple roots.

Answer (score 0):

Spline: [bezier clipping](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch7.pdf).
Polynomial: [Viète's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formulas) (to get the zeroes, I *think*).
Line: [line-line](http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/intersections/intersectionOfTwoLines1/intersectionOfTwoLines1.html).

Not a trivial question (or solution) under any circumstance.